# Displaying winner in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to display the victor in an HTML table. I have my table set up like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/yrrq76oh/1/ and then on the server side I am trying to figure out how to display the results if team1 beats team2 then it should update the box where team2 plays team1. So if team1 beats team2, it should display "wins" in the team1-team2 box and "loses" in the team2-team1 box. This is what I have so far in my `server.js`:

```
app.post("/passScores", function(req, res){
   var someScores = {};
   someScores.a = req.body.a;
   someScores.b = req.body.b;
   var team1 = parseInt(someScores.a);
   var team2 = parseInt(someScores.b);


   if(team1 > team2){
     res.write("Win");
    }

   else if(team1 == team2){
     res.write("Draw");
   }
   else{
     res.write("Lose")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your jsfiddle, since the ajax call cant reach the server, I do it in the pure client side app. Hope it is helpful.
https://jsfiddle.net/kingychiu/yrrq76oh/6/

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#submit').on('click', function(){
           var match = [['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f'], ['g','h'], ['i','j'], ['k','l']];

           scores = {
               a: $("#a").val(), b: $("#b").val(), c: $("#c").val(), d: $("#d").val(),
               e: $("#e").val(), f: $("#f").val(), g: $("#g").val(), h: $("#h").val(),
               i: $("#i").val(), j: $("#j").val(), k: $("#k").val(), l: $("#l").val()   
           };

           for(var i = 0; i < match.length ; i++){
             console.log(match[i])
             var teamScore1 = $("#"+match[i][0]).val();
             var teamScore2 = $("#"+match[i][1]).val();
             if(teamScore1 > teamScore2){
              $("#"+match[i][0]).val($("#"+match[i][0]).val()+'Win');
              $("#"+match[i][1]).val($("#"+match[i][1]).val()+'Lose');
              }
             else if(teamScore2 > teamScore1){
              $("#"+match[i][0]).val($("#"+match[i][0]).val()+'Lose');
              $("#"+match[i][1]).val($("#"+match[i][1]).val()+'Win');
              }
             else{
              $("#"+match[i][0]).val($("#"+match[i][0]).val()+'Draw');
              $("#"+match[i][1]).val($("#"+match[i][1]).val()+'Draw');
             }

           }   
           });

       });
```

Comment: I am trying to make it so the results of team1 playing against team2 on team1's schedule will automatically update the results of team2 against team1 (since they are essentially the same match).